# XSLT condition output one by one

Tags: xml, function, xslt, if-statement, xpath

I need to have in each 'a', all the 'b' that have @n greater than or equal to the @n of the 'a' in which they are contained.

I am using XSLT 2.0 and Saxon-HE 9.6.0.5

---

XML source:

```
<blabla>
    <a n="2"></a>
    <a n="6"></a>
    <b n="6"></b>
    <b n="1"></b>
    <b n="4"></b>
</blabla>
```

---

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">   

<xsl:template match="blabla">
    <all>
        <xsl:for-each select="//a">
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="n" select="./@n"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//b">
                    <xsl:if test="./@n[. >= //a/@n]">
                        <b>
                            <xsl:attribute name="n" select="./@n"/>
                        </b>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </all>
</xsl:template>
```

---

What I would like to have is:

```
<all>
    <a n="2">
        <b n="6"/>
        <b n="4"/>
    </a>
    <a n="6">
        <b n="6"/>
    </a>
</all>
```

---

What I have instead is:

```
<all>
    <a n="2">
        <b n="6"/>
        <b n="4"/>
    </a>
    <a n="6">
        <b n="6"/>
        <b n="4"/>
    </a>
</all>
```

I am not sure if the whole approach is wrong or if I have to adjust something.

Just for completeness, this is the function with which I was trying to do the same thing. The output is NOTHING when I create elements inside the function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foo="http://whatever">

<xsl:function name="foo:test">
    <xsl:param name="a"/>
    <xsl:param name="b"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$a">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="n">
                <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="$b >= $a">
                <b>
                    <xsl:attribute name="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </b>
            </xsl:if>
        </a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    test 1: <xsl:value-of select="foo:test(//a/@n, //b/@n)"/>
    test 2: <xsl:value-of select="foo:test(7, 6)"/>
    test 3: <xsl:value-of select="foo:test(3, 6)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

The same function, without creating elements, works fine with numbers, but not if I put as parameters the xpath expression that match the source document (it outputs everything).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:foo="http://whatever">

<xsl:function name="foo:foo:test">
    <xsl:param name="a"/>
    <xsl:param name="b"/>
        <xsl:if test="$b >= $a">
        a: <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
        b: <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>
        </xsl:if>   
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    test 1: <xsl:value-of select="foo:test(//a/@n, //b/@n)"/>
    test 2: <xsl:value-of select="foo:test(7, 6)"/>
    test 3: <xsl:value-of select="foo:test(3, 6)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    test 1: 
        a: 2 6
        b: 6 1 4
    test 2: 
    test 3: 
        a: 3
        b: 6
```

I don't need to do it with a function; if you have suggestions for doing it without a function, it is fine.

Comment: Incidentally, the way you have written your title suggests you're not really "thinking XSLT" yet. You never want to do things "one by one" if you can do them all at once in a single batch.

Comment: You main mistake was `<xsl:if test="./@n[. >= //a/@n]">`. This compares the b element with all the a elements in the whole document, not just the one you are currently processing. In fact, your code seems to use leading "//" as if it's magic fairy dust: you need to read about the context node and relative paths.

Comment: Thank you!! It's true, I am a beginner and I was struggling writing the title, which is not at all a good sign. Now it works. Ahah, I would love to have magic fairy dust, but those '//' should be what remains of a more nested xml that I simplified for asking advice, sorry. Thanks for solution and comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="blabla">
    <all>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <a n="{@n}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="../b[@n >= current()/@n]"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </all>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSL 1.0 solution (also works with XSL 2.0 and is compatible with any XSL processor) that uses multiple templates and parameter passing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/blabla">
    <all>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="level-1">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="@n" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </all>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a" mode="level-1">
    <xsl:variable name="threshold" select="@n" />
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="n"><xsl:value-of select="$threshold" /></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//b" mode="level-2">
        <xsl:with-param name="threshold" select="$threshold" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b" mode="level-2">
    <xsl:param name="threshold" />
    <xsl:if test="number(@n) &gt;= number($threshold)">
      <b>
        <xsl:attribute name="n"><xsl:value-of select="@n" /></xsl:attribute>
      </b>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```